# WPF Richtextbox multiple colors and font

Tags: wpf-controls, vb.net-2010

```
    Public Sub ChatMessage(ByVal sUser As String, ByVal sMessage As String)
    Dim tmpData As String = sUser & ":" & vbTab & sMessage
    Dim p As Paragraph = New Paragraph(New Run(tmpData))
    p.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightGreen
    p.FontSize = 12
    p.Margin = New System.Windows.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)

    RoomMessages.RichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(p)
    RoomMessages.RichTextBox.ScrollToEnd()      

End Sub
```

I have added a WPF Richtextbox called RoomMessages to a Windows form.
I can add text using the code above  and it works for adding text with 1 color and font. I need to be able to change the colors of words before adding them to the richtextbox. I have searched for days but no luck.

Ive seen C# code using TextRange or TextBlocks but havnt been able to  get them to work in VB

Answer (score 0):

```
         tUser.Text = sUser & ":"
    tUser.Foreground = New System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightGreen)

    tMessage.Text = sMessage
    tUser.Foreground = New System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.White)

    P.Inlines.Add(tUser)
    P.Inlines.Add(tMessage)

    P.FontSize = 12
    p.Margin = New System.Windows.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)
```